# Querying by support of a Hash Map

Tags: ruby

I need to make a "complex" group by query in ruby. My records has the follow format:

```
{[
value => {nil}
value => {nil}
value => {nil}
value => {4}
value => {0}
value => {7}
value => {nil}
value => {nil}
value => {nil}
value => {nil}
value => { 8]
value => { 90}
value => { 90}
value => { nil}
value => { nil}
]}
.
.
.
```

I need to group by neighboor different of nil. How can I get that?. In my example the output will be

```
#id value
value => {4} 
value => {0}
value => {7}

#id value
value => { 8}
value => { 90}
value => { 90}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing looks like a valid Ruby object in your example.

If you can get your data to look like an array, you could use [`Enumerable#chunk`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) to group consecutive non-nil objects into sub-arrays :

```
data = [nil, nil, nil, 4, 0, 7, nil, nil, nil, 8, 90, 90]
data.chunk{ |x| x.nil? }.reject{ |is_nil, _| is_nil }.map{ |_, group| group }
# [[4, 0, 7], [8, 90, 90]]
```